# CSS inheritance and overriding it

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS. Ive created a Drupal site and playing with the theme.

I have some breadcrumb stuff that I would like to theme. If I go into Firebug and turn off the CSS properties

```
background
border-color
border-style
```

in the below code

```
.breadcrumbs .inner {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EFEFEF;
    border-color: #929292 #E2E2E2 #FFFFFF;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: #8E8E8E;
}
```

I get the text looking exactly how I want it.

If I now go into my style.css which is inheriting the code and post

```
.breadcrumbs .inner {
    border-width: 1px;
    color: #8E8E8E;
}
```

The formatting I don't want is retained. If I specify `.breadcrumbs .inner` in the style.css does that not set it up again and override what was specified higher up the cascade?

If that is not the case how do I stop the inheritance without changing the other style sheet?

Thanks,

Andrew

Additional Info

Here is what I have at the moment

[image]

This is what I want to have
[image]

Comment: Use !important after every property which you want to override. like `display:inline !important;`

Comment: @BoltClock I know it's bad practice. Alternatively, just resetting the properties would do fine, I suppose, if it is exactly the same selector and defined after the first one, using for example `background:transparent;` should override the first declaration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're overriding CSS does not replace the 3 styles you want to change, so the original ones are maintained.  What you likely want to do is have your style.css set something like this:

```
.breadcrumbs .inner {
    background: none;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I tried that, refreshed the cache etc and there was no change what else should I try?

Comment: @Andrew: Based off the screenshots you've added, style.css did not contain any definition for `.breadcrumbs .inner`  When you say you refreshed the cache, did you empty all your temporary internet files then reload the page. Also try <CTRL>+F5, sometimes F5 alone just doesn't do it. Other than that, I would double check to make sure you have your CSS links in the order you want them (ie: style.css after gray.css)

Comment: Just a side note, on chrome you can right click on the refresh button and choose empty cache and hard reload

Answer (score 5):

If you specify the CSS styles for same classes twice the resulting style is a union of the attributes defined in both classes. To remove the previous styles you have to redefine the attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply could you clarify a little more what you mean? I don't know whether I have been lucky but when I have followed a similar method as I indicated in my original post the changes applied.

Answer (score 3):

If for example you have these css attached to your html document

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/posts.css">
```

if you have the same class say .color defined in the both default.css and posts.css files, you would imagine that that last css file will be used, but it can be ignored if you write it like so:

```
// default.css
.color {
   color: blue !important;
}

// posts.css
.color {
   color: green;
}
// In this example the colour would be blue.
```

Using !important on inherited style forces inherited style to be used, if you want to override the inherited style then you can simply add !important to post.css

```
// default.css
.color {
   color: blue !important;
}

// posts.css
.color {
   color: green !important;
}
// In this example the colour would be green.
```

Now both are viewed as important and the last one will be used.